# input format specific regex

Tags: regex, validation

i want that my input text repect this format :

start with P0E and 10 digits:

P0E0532313118

how i can do it with jquery or java script please  ?

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Pure JS:**

```
let value = 'P0E0532313118';
let isValid =  /^(P0E[0-9]{10})$/.test(value);    // = TRUE
```